# SVN export ignoring missing files, how?

Tags: svn

I have a large, old working copy of svn repository that I checked out long time ago. I'd like to export and save it preserving the directory structure.

Over time, I've deleted most of the sub-directories and files at various levels as unneeded. I'd like to export the rest using `svn export`.

However, the export stops unfinished due to errors like this:

```
svn: Can't stat 'WSN/Somedir': No such file or directory
```

I'd like to avoid `svn update` due to following reasons:

- The repository is old and not served any more
- Even if it would be online, the missing directories are many gigabytes that I would rather not spend time and space downloading.

One solution I know is to copy the whole tree and to run recursive delete command that removes all ".svn" directories.

However, is there a cleaner way, to ask `svn` for export that ignores missing files and directories?

Answer (score 0):

If you run `svn status`, you will get a list of missing assets. They are signaled with the `!` characters; e.g.:

```
$ svn status
?       default.cfg
!       models
```

In this example the `models` folder was deleted and is thus marked with a `!`.

To fix this you need to delete these missing folders with `svn rm`; in the example this would be:

```
$ svn rm models
D         models
D         models/model1.png
D         models/model2.png
```

Then commit and the export should work afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can revert just that sub directory.
Do this by changing directory to the folder you want to revert, so you don't revert the wrong thing. Then enter:

> svn revert -R .

Now you can update and export as you like.